# Two jquery functions work on click, but together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So when I click once it does both the Jquery codes ... I would like it that when I
click it slides down and stays down until I click again, how to?

I tried click1 and click2 but it is not ideal.
I also tried giving them other id but it wasn't logical.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideDown(1500);
    });
});
</script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideUp(1500);
    });
});
</script>


<style> 
#panel, #flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen, when you attach multiple handlers they all execute at the same time. Instead, attach one handler and call `slideToggle()` instead.

Also note that you may want to add a call to `stop()` in there so that when the element is clicked rapidly the animations do not queue up. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip").click(function() {
    $("#panel").stop(true).slideToggle(1500);
  });
});
```

```css
#panel,
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
       if($('#panel').is(':visible')){
           $("#panel").slideUp(1500);
       }else{
           $("#panel").slideDown(1500);
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there are two click events bound to the div.  Instead, you need to keep track of the state (i.e. isUp or isDown) and do it with a single click handler.  Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isDown = false;
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        if( !isDown ){
            $("#panel").slideDown(1500);
            isDown = true;
        } else {
            $("#panel").slideUp(1500);
            isDown = false;
        }
    });
});
```